# Why i get this following error when using dir in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Matlab keep give me following error message :

??? Error using ==> dir
Argument must contain a string.

Error in ==> Awal at 15
    x = dir(subDirs)

Below is my codes :

```
%MY PROGRAM

clear all;
clc;
close all;

%-----Create Database-----
TrainDB = uigetdir('','Select Database Directory');
TrainFiles = dir(TrainDB);
dirIndex = [TrainFiles.isdir];
[s subDirNumber] = size(dirIndex);
for i = 3:subDirNumber
    subDirs = {TrainFiles(i).name};
    subDirs = strcat(TrainDB,'\',subDirs);
    x = dir(subDirs) %<-------Error Here
end
```

Is something wrong with the codes? Your help will be appreciated.
I'm sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with this line:

```
subDirs = {TrainFiles(i).name};
```

When you strcat on the next line, you are strcat-ing two strings with a cell containing a string. The result in subDirs is a cell containing a string which dir() apparently doesn't like. You can either use

```
subDirs = TrainFiles(i).name;
```

or

```
x = dir(subDirs(1))
```

I would recommend the first option.

Comment: Oh, yes. I did not notice if it was not a string but the cell. Thank you for your help Justin.

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code I get the error message:

```
??? Error using ==> dir
Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.
```

What MATLAB is telling you is that when you call `dir(subDirs)` `subDirs` is a cell rather than a string which is what `dir` wants.  Something like `dir(subDirs{1,1})` will do what (I think) you want.  I'll leave it to you to rewrite your code.

Answer (score 1):

with `subDirs = {TrainFiles(i).name};` you create a cell-array of stings. `dir` is not defined for that type. Just omit the `{}` around the name

BTW: Your code does not only list directories, but all files. Check `find` on the `isdir` attribute to get only directory's indices!